# What is the block number of the first block mined in a private blockchain network deployed on say Quorum?

Tags: azure, blockchain, mining, quorum, azure-blockchain-workbench

I am working on POCs on Azure Blockchain Service. While working on quickstarts, I observed that while deploying my 'Hello Blockchain!' smart contract, the block number of the block mined was 34136. Since I deployed a new consortium network, why was the block number so huge? I expected block number to be 1 or say 2.

Answer (score 0):

When you deployed Workbench, did you bring your own Blockchain endpoint or let Workbench create one for you?

If you are not bringing your own Blockchain endpoint, Workbench will create one instance of Azure Blockchain Service as the underlying Blockchain consortium resource.  As configured, the Blockchain will generate block at least every 5 mins even no contract/transaction is deployed.

Comment: If you had a Blockchain Service before you could point workbench to that - See this blogpost: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-blockchain-workbench-1-7-0-integration-with-azure-blockchain-service/